# alfresco Custom Data List Form nested set

Tags: xml, alfresco, alfresco-share

I am making a custom form in alfresco that has a lot of fields for storing general information on employees as a reference for managers. According to the alfresco documentation [here](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Forms) and [here](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Forms_Examples) nested sets or groups are allowed but I get a cryptic message when I try to create a new item in the data list area and the modal doesn't come up. Do data list forms specifically not support the parent parameter?

this is done is the `share-config-custom.xml` file in the web-extension directory:

```
<appearance> 
  <set id="General" appearance="title" label="General Information" />
  <set id="Educated" appearance="title" label="Education" />
  <set id="Skilled" appearance="title" label="Skillls/Talent/Area of Expertise" /> 
  <set id="triple" appearance="" parent="Educated" label="none" />
```

The documentation says nothing about this not working for data lists. I'm using alfresco version 4.2

Answer (score 1):

"**Set**" is just for logical grouping of properties in the user interface it will not change anything in the model. 
So it's like you need to define the set then for all properties which you want to club together you add id of that set as attribute

```
<set id="dublin-core" appearance="bordered-panel" label="Dublin Core" />
           <field id="cm:publisher" set="dublin-core" />
```

As given in this wiki example "dublin-core" is set defined for all properties related to that aspect. 
Now I do not see any properties included in your configuration. That must be the cause of your error. Also your custom data list item which you have defined in the model should have "cm:datalistItem" as parent.
Check this out for more details.

http://blog.arvixe.com/create-custom-datalist-in-alfresco/

Comment: you've literally just given me the same samples that are in the links i provided, This is not the answer, i tried it for data lists and it wasn't functioning properly